# Kendo menu selects multiple items at a time, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

I have Kendo menu with actions:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu().Name("menu")
.Items(it => {                                       
       it.Add().Text("Item1").Items(subit => {
                subit.Add().Text("subitem1).Action("Contracts", "Home");
                subit.Add().Text("subitem2").Action("Contracts", "Home",
                                                       new { flag = true });
 });
 })
)
```

My problem is that whenever I select `subitem1` or `subitem2` the items get both selected (class `.k-state-selected` added to both items).
I guess that it happens because I have the same controller actions. I wouldn't like to create separate action for `subitem2`. Is there any workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just for some context, what is the reason for having 2 links navigating to the same page like you have in the example?

Comment: That's actually what Kendo does: it checks the current URL and sets the `k-state-selected` class on items pointing to it.

Comment: @gerdi, they return views with different data based on the route values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not not if this works because i do not have the kendo library and i cant seem to test it properly at http://dojo.telerik.com/ but basically

> Fires before a sub menu gets opened.

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
     open: function(e) {
           if (location.search != "") {
               $('#menu #item a:first').removeClass('.k-state-selected');
        }
     }
 });
```

It then looks to see if the url has properties, as per the [location.search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) and if it does then it removes the kendo class from the menu first menu item, which is not the one passing anything.

I am not sure how kendo builds its items, but you might also want to check out if on activate would work better

> Fires when a sub menu gets opened and its animation finished.

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
     activate: function(e) {
         // handle event
     }
});
```